# Embed RadDataForm inside RadListView/ListView

Tags: angularjs, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I need to use the Stepper component from the nativescript-pro-ui, however it is not a standalone component but it needs to be wrapped by RadDataForm.
What i am trying to do is to loop through a list of available menus returned from a REST api for user to order.

I have created a playground here: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=vwvuXt

As you can see, i bind the [source] of the RadDataForm to individual item from the ListView. However, this way the RadDataForm does not display.

If I change it to use *ngFor, it works. So, what is wrong with the binding with RadDataForm, is there anyway to achieve it?

The template code that use the *ngFor is like this:

```
<RadDataForm *ngFor="let item of menus" tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton [source]="item">
    <TKEntityProperty tkDataFormProperty name="name" [isReadOnly]="isReadOnly" displayName="Name" index="0"></TKEntityProperty>
    <TKEntityProperty tkDataFormProperty name="price" [isReadOnly]="isReadOnly" displayName="Price" index="1"></TKEntityProperty>
    <TKEntityProperty tkDataFormProperty name="image" [isReadOnly]="isReadOnly" displayName="Image" index="2"></TKEntityProperty>
    <TKEntityProperty tkDataFormProperty name="quantity" displayName="Quantity" index="3">
        <TKPropertyEditor tkEntityPropertyEditor type="Stepper"></TKPropertyEditor>
    </TKEntityProperty>
</RadDataForm>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember my friend, you need to use the NativeScript layouts to avoid wrong behaviors in all platforms. So to fix the issue of your example, the code is the following:

```
<ListView [items]="menus">
    <ng-template let-item="item">
        <StackLayout>
            <RadDataForm #myDish [source]="item" tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton>
                <TKEntityProperty tkDataFormProperty name="name" displayName="Dish Name" index="0">
                    <TKPropertyEditor tkEntityPropertyEditor type="Text">
                    </TKPropertyEditor>
                </TKEntityProperty>
            </RadDataForm>
        </StackLayout>
    </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

As you can see we are using StackLayout for each field of the list. Also, you can use the [RadListView](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/ListView/getting-started) component, you can find more advanced features like infinite scrolling, pull to refresh, etc.